# Manifest file for .NET Application and OCX

Tags: .net, windows, manifest, ocx

I have an test application with this C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ArchivoManifest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FiscalPrinterLib.HASAR hasar = new FiscalPrinterLib.HASAR();
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The object **HASAR** is contained in **Fiscal051122.ocx** ([link](https://mega.co.nz/#!qkIUQIyJ!1WGIOPCrZpOL-W_twFNkhHMre0XNP8_AQYQeIF6wBgs)). To avoid use regSvr32 to register the OCX file, need create manifest file for ArchivoManifest.exe and Fiscal051122.ocx.

Try different ways but not work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Just let the build system write the manifest for you.  Set the Isolated property of the assembly reference to True.

Comment: Super! Thank you very much Hans :)